# Split DbContext in EF Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a database with 150+ tables. I use EF Core 5 for a ASP.NET Core wen application and would like to ask if it is a good idea to have all my tables in 1 DbContext. If yes what about performance?

I'm thinking to split it in multiple DbContexts but what happens with migration, transactions and table relations?

After searching, I found a hint about "classic" Entity Framework (not Core) that said to hold 1 DbContext and split it as shown below:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Employers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> { get; set; }
}
```

> If you wanted to make a driving module, you might only use People, Cars, & Trips. If you wanted a payroll module, you might only use Company, Employee, & People. So you would need the following interfaces:

```
public interface IDrivingContext
{
    DbSet<Person> People { get; }
    DbSet<Vehicle> Cars { get; }
    DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; }
}

public interface IPayrollContext
{
    DbSet<Person> People { get; }
    DbSet<Company> Employers { get; }
    DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; }
}
```

> Then you change your context to implement both interfaces:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IDrivingContext, IPayrollContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Employers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> { get; set; }
}

And when you use the DbContext, only type the variable as IDrivingContext or IPayrollContext, depending on which module you are coding inside of:

using (IDrivingContext db = new MyDbContext())
{
     // ...
}

using (IPayrollContext db = new MyDbContext())
{
    // ...
}
```

I do not understand what the benefits of this implementation. The function `OnModelCreating` of DbContext will be execute for all DbSets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits are that you retain a single `DbContext` while still providing the ability to have individual repositories.  Each interface "filters" the `DbSet`s down to only those that apply to a particular repository.

For what it's worth, I think you're probably worrying too much about the cost of setting up that DbContext.  DbContext objects are designed to be lightweight, easily stood up for a database operation or sequence of operations, and then torn down immediately afterwards.

Comment: So reading between the lines - regarding OPs orginal question:

Is a good idea to have all my tables in 1 DbContext. If yes what about performance?


....      Either single or multiple DbContext are fine and the performance impact would be negligible (compared to other aspects of the application) . Correct?

Comment: In my experience, the only performance hit you’ll take is on application startup when the dbcontext first builds its internal model. Lots of dbsets in a context shouldn’t noticeably impact query or instantiation performance.

Comment: So the suggestion is to create 1 DbContext!  Correct? Any other opinion?

Comment: Well, I could give you another opinion, but this is the correct one.

Comment: Could you please take a look in that site? [link]https://dzone.com/articles/strategies-for-improving-the-performance-of-applic

Comment: Is says in hte end "Hence, rather than using a large db context, you should split the db context into multiple db context"

Comment: The only way you're really going to know for sure if performance is a problem in your application is to *measure it.*  You already told us that there are penalties for your application to break it into multiple DbContexts.  So put it all into one context, *measure the performance,* and see if it is adequate or not.

Comment: And for what it's worth, that article offers what seems like bad advice, like turning off change tracking and disabling lazy loading.  Only do these things if 1. You have identified an *actual* performance problem in your application by measuring, 2.  You have determined that the problem is *solved* by using these techniques, and 3.  You understand the *tradeoffs* for using these techniques and are willing to live with those tradeoffs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you very much for your help!